# textArea inside jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

How can i create a **text area** inside a dialog box and that text area should be mandatory field created using jQuery UI. Below is the code through which i am creating submit and close buttons on the dialog box, but could not able to create text area which should be mandatory field when the user click on submit button through that code.Please suggest. Please find the working sample http://jsfiddle.net/M4QM6/34/ .

```
    function showDialog1(){
        $("#dialog").html("");
        $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", "Loading....").dialog("open");
        $("span.ui-dialog-title").text('title here'); 
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: true,
            width:"350",
            height:300,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Put a `textarea` with an `id` in the `#dialog` `div`. Add a class to hide the `div`. Remove `$("#dialog").html("");`. Examine the `textarea` valie in the buttons event.

Answer (score 3):

Insert after the `$("#dialog").("html")`; the  following: 
    `$("#dialog").append('<textarea    class="mandatory"></textarea>')`;

And before you submit, check for the textarea by his class to have some value.

```
if($(".mandatory").text().lenght>0) {
// do submit
} else {
// show error message(eg. Mesaage must       not be empty)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, by adding the `textarea` tag inside `html()` as below,

```
Dialog1<input type="submit" value="dialog1" onclick="return showDialog1()"/>
<div id="dialog"></div>
<br>
    <script>
                function showDialog1(){
        $("#dialog").html("<textarea name="testArea" required cols='5' rows='3'>your text here</textarea>");
            $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", "Loading....").dialog("open");
            $("span.ui-dialog-title").text('title here'); 
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: true,
                width:"350",
                height:300,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

You could make it  mandatory field by adding `required` attribute

see the updated [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/San_Krish/M4QM6/36/) here

Answer (score 1):

Well... just put a `<textarea>` inside `#dialog`:

```
$("#dialog").html("<textarea id="myarea" />");
```

Validation should be done upon submitting the form:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    if ($("#myarea").text() === "" ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI will display in the modal the text/html you put in `#dialog`

```js
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: true,
        width: "350",
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                // if textarea is not empty close the modal and do something with the value
                if ($(this).find('textarea').val().length) $(this).dialog("close");
                else $(this).find('textarea').css({borderColor: 'red'});
            }
        }
    });
});

function showDialog1() {
    $('#dialog').find('textarea').val(''); // clear textarea on modal open
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", "Loading....").dialog("open");
    $("span.ui-dialog-title").text('title here');
}
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Dialog1
<input type="submit" value="dialog1" onclick="return showDialog1()" />
<div id="dialog">
    <p>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </p>
</div>
<br>
```